# What does Redis Queues suffix ':reserved' means?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, redis, queue

I am using Laravel 5.5, with 'Redis' as Queue provider.

Inside Redis keys I have the queues keys, like 'queues:batch', and also keys like 'queues:batch:reserved'.

What are these for? And which elements go to this key?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The keys that end in `:reserved` are jobs that have been picked up by a queue worker to be worked on. They get marked as `:reserved` while being executed so that another queue worker doesn't pick up the same job.

You can read up a little more on how the queues work on the divinglaravel.com site: https://divinglaravel.com/queue-workers-how-they-work